# Control browser back in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, back-button

In Angular 2, is there a better way to control browser back. 
Ex: when click on back, show confirm dialog box, if confirmed redirect to page X, otherwise stay in same page.

Using location.onPopState() we cannot have a complete control on browser back as it will eventually do the back redirect.

Can above behavior be achieved using authguard, canActivate of angular2 routing?

Answer (score 1):

WHat you are looking for is the `canDeactivate` guard.  Victor describes it like this in his book:

> The canDeactivate guard is different from the rest. Its main purpose is not to check permissions,
>   but to ask for confirmation. To illustrate this let’s change the application to ask for confirmation
>   when the user closes the compose dialog with unsaved changes.

He then goes on to share how to do a `SaveChanges` guard:

```
   canDeactivate(component: ComposeCmp, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
   state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
      if (component.unsavedChanges) {
        return this.dialogs.unsavedChangesConfirmationDialog();
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
      }
    }
```

I highly suggest buying the book. https://leanpub.com/router